# Not displaying message when no records found

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

For some reason, the below is not showing the "No results found" error message  when querying the database for a selected range, but is displaying the table header and footer.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblRecords WHERE DATE(RecDate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY RecDate DESC, RecTime DESC");

<?php

if (!$result) { echo("No results found for the selected view");
          } else ?>
          <table id="results">
<tr>
<th>Rec#</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Reading</th>
</tr>
<?php ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
?>
<tr>

<td><?php echo($row['RecID']);?></td>
<td><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['RecDate'])));?></td>
<td><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['RecTime'])));?></td>
<td><?php echo($row['RecReading'] . $row['RecMeasure']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td class="footer" colspan="4">- end of report -</td></tr>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as theoretically, this should work... Shouldn't it? :-)

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see how you're creating `$result`

Comment: True @PatrickQ ... I have updated showing the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this condition to check the number of row in query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblRecords WHERE DATE(RecDate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY RecDate DESC, RecTime DESC");

<?php

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) { 
    echo("No results found for the selected view");
} else {?>
<table id="results">
<tr>
<th>Rec#</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Reading</th>
</tr>
<?php ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
?>
<tr>

<td><?php echo($row['RecID']);?></td>
<td><?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['RecDate'])));?></td>
<td><?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['RecTime'])));?></td>
<td><?php echo($row['RecReading'] . $row['RecMeasure']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td class="footer" colspan="4">- end of report -</td></tr>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Is there any advantage or disadvantage to this vs `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) { echo("No results found for the selected view");` or is this another way to do the same thing? :-)

Comment: no both are same as results are never gonna negative and minimum count is always 0 so I preferred that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 3):

`$result` is probably a result set but it might be empty. yet `!$result` will not be true. documentation for `mysql_query`:

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`. (source: http://php.net/mysqli_query)

you should check with `mysqli_num_rows` (or something similar)

Comment: correct... for the if statement I replaced it to `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) { echo("No results found for the selected view");` and now works as it should :-) Thanks @jakumi